# JS Code working in Chrome but Not IE using IE 8 mode

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, javascript, development, jquery

Any ideas what may be causing this?

This code runs fine in Chrome.

```
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script><!-- load jquery -->

            <script type="text/javascript">

            //start of jQuery document ready section
                function checkListItems(region, time)
                {//start of function

                var basePath = "https://sp.test.com/sp/ts/"; //This is your base site url with "/_api/" appended to the end
                var listName = "CharlesSchwabMeetingsShane"; //This is where you put the name of your picture library

                //start of Ajax query
                jQuery.ajax({
                //
                //This is where you add the fields you would like to return after the "select=". Separate fields by a ","
                url: basePath + "_vti_bin/listdata.svc/"+listName+"?$select=Name,Time1,Region1,IndividualMeetings&$expand=Region1,Time1,IndividualMeetings", 
                //
                type: "GET", //This is set to GET so it can pull the data properly
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }, //This just sets the data to be returned as json data
                success: function (data) //data is a system variable which contains the data returned from the server
                {
                jQuery.each(data.d.results, function (index, value) 
                //index is the index of items
                //value is the item being receieved
                //data.d is the serialized data value from the query, and adding .results to the end gets the results of the serialized data
                {
                     if(value.Region1.Id == region && value.Time1.Id == time)
                     {
                         //console.log(value.IndividualMeetings); -Show just the object details in the console
                         $("#ctl00_m_g_840c396b_fbc8_44f2_ba14_0aef5e4d34f0_ctl00_ctl05_ctl03_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_DropDownChoice option[value='"+value.IndividualMeetings.Value.toString()+"']").hide();
                         //$("#select1 option:contains(Text)").remove(); -Alternative removal method
                     }
                });
                },
                error: function (data) 
                {
                //Error gets output here
                alert(data.statusText); //data.statusText displays the status of the call
                },
                complete: function()
                {
                //Insert any code here that you want to run when the ajax call has completed
                }

                });//End of Ajax query


                }//end of function


            $(document).ready(function() {
                alert("test");
                //Listen for changes to time drop down start
                $('#ctl00_m_g_840c396b_fbc8_44f2_ba14_0aef5e4d34f0_ctl00_ctl05_ctl02_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_Lookup').change(function() {
                    selectedRegion = document.getElementById('ctl00_m_g_840c396b_fbc8_44f2_ba14_0aef5e4d34f0_ctl00_ctl05_ctl01_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_Lookup').value; //Gets the Region1 value
                    selectedTimeId = $(this).val();  //This gets the value of the drop down that we are listening for (Time1)
                    $("#ctl00_m_g_840c396b_fbc8_44f2_ba14_0aef5e4d34f0_ctl00_ctl05_ctl03_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_DropDownChoice").children('option').show(); //Resets so all corresponding times show
                    checkListItems(selectedRegion,selectedTimeId); //Call ajax call to check list entries
                });
                //Listen for changes to time drop down end

            });</script>
```

Comment: Change jQuery version to 1.12.4 and check. Afaik,version 3.xx doesn't work on ie8

Comment: @GautamSheth That didn't resolve the issue, if I go to IE 10/11 it works though aside from the .change() function in the javascript call.

Comment: @GautamSheth The issue was using the min version of jquery 3.2.1. Once I used the full version it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was using the min version of jquery 3.2.1. Once I used the full version it worked just fine.

Also to hide or show select options I had to use the attr/removeattr feature.